# pull out images alt in wordpress attachment page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a code for wordpress attachment page that shows other images of the parent post in attachment page

```
function bdw_get_images() {
 global $post;
    // Get images for this post
    $arrImages = get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $post->post_parent );
 
    // If images exist for this page
    if($arrImages) {
        foreach ( $arrImages as $img ) {
        
            // Build the <img> string
            $sImgString =            '
            <li class="item">
          <div class="thumb">
          <a href="' . get_attachment_link( $img->ID ) . '">' .
                                wp_get_attachment_image( $img->ID, 'thumbnail') .
                            '</a>
          </div>
        </li>';
            // Print the image
            echo $sImgString;

        } //end foreach
    } //end if
}
```

it woks fine and show the other image with everything including Alt,
but I want to show ALT text below any images.
what should I use?
like this:

[image]